# What am I doing wrong when using navigation properties versus using FK properties?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

When I use the following code in an MVC4 action method, I get the error just below it:

```
var role = _roleRepository.GetByName(model.RegistrationType.ToString());
var mr = new MemberRole();
mr.Priority = int.MaxValue;
mr.IsActive = true;
entity.MemberRoles.Add(mr);
role.MemberRoles.Add(mr);
_roleRepository.Update(role);
_memberRepository.Insert(entity);
```

*A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.*

I sort of understand that, but needing to move and and deliver, tried the following approach, giving the error below it. I assumed I couldn't update the role yet, because one of its `MemberRole` 'children' didn't have a valid `Member` reference (FK):

```
var role = _roleRepository.GetByName(model.RegistrationType.ToString());
var mr = new MemberRole();
mr.Priority = int.MaxValue;
mr.IsActive = true;
entity.MemberRoles.Add(mr);
role.MemberRoles.Add(mr);
//_roleRepository.Update(role);
_memberRepository.Insert(entity);
```

*The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint FK_MemberRole_Role_RoleId. The conflict occurred in database Educ8, table dbo.Role, column Id.*

I finally achieved success using only FK properties on the MemberRole, as follows, and all is peaceful and good:

```
_memberRepository.Insert(entity);
var role = _roleRepository.GetByName(model.RegistrationType.ToString());
var mr = new MemberRole();
mr.MemberId = entity.Id;
mr.RoleId = role.Id;
mr.Priority = int.MaxValue;
mr.IsActive = true;
_memberRoleRepository.Insert(mr);
```

My fluent mappings and entity classes are fine, it's just that I'm doing something wrong, w.r.t. order of updates I suspect, and haven't a clue what.

Comment: Not a full explanation but part of the problem is that the new `MemberRole` is saved by two repositories (and I assume two different contexts).

Comment: @GertArnold, I assume you refer to my first code sample. Yes, you are correct it is two context instances. May I presume this could also have an effect in the second, where `role` and `entity` belong to two different instances?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that's part of the problem. It may help to save the `mr` first by one context, dispose the context and then add the `mr` to the other `MemberRoles`.